# angularjs and decimal point is comma

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

Some countries use in numbers the point as comma and the comma as decimal.
[Wiki Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark)
This countries are Europe (except UK and Ireland), SudAmerica, Russia and French West Afica.

How is know if the user of Web in HTML5 is "Decimal point is Comma" or "Comma is Comma"?
Or I must have got a database of Languages with this data and it use in angular `lang={{lang}}`

Comment: Please, read about `.toLocaleString()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: Angular supports [i18n](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n).  Check all of the available locales [here](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-i18n/).  Most notably, the `NUMBER_FORMAT`.  [Here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.2.15/angular-locale_ru.js) is Russia, and you can see the `DECIMAL_SEP` is `","`

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot know enough about the user by using HTML5. It's up to them to tell you, since they could be living outside their country of origin. Once they tell you where they're from, you can use Angular internationalization features to help you format the various things:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

If you need to dive further into translation, there are multiple plugins to do so:

https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate

https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/